# What is the purpose of File and Folder with same name in Zend Library?

Tags: zend-framework

if you open your zend library you can see Folder named Acl and also Acl.php & same is the case for other libraries of Zend.
i am wonder why Zend doing so ??
what's the Logic Behind This ??

Comment: Read this http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does so you don't need to write code `require_once'Zend/Acl.php'`

Zend register its autoloader on spl autoloader stack . When you do

```
$acl = new Zend_Acl();
```

without require or include . Php ask Zend autoloader to locate file where definition of  class Zend_Acl can be found . What Zend autoloader do in reply is to take input 'Zend_Acl' replace `'_'` with directory separator and add '.php' extension at the end and do `include('Zend/Acl.php') ;` by itself.

since library directory is part of php include_path hence it work.

Answer (score 4):

This is because of:

1. Naming convention for classes
2. Convention of class <-> file name (path) relation

If you have a class that is related to some other class, it is logical to name them accordingly, for example `Zend_Form_Element` and `Zend_Form`.

Now you come to the relation between class name and file name / path. Since the rule is simple: replace `_` in class name with `/` in file path, you end up with:

`Zend_Form` -> `Zend/Form`(.php)

and

`Zend_Form_Element` -> `Zend/Form/Element`(.php)

This is how you got the file `Form.php` and directory `Form`.